# codeigniter validation_errors() empty yet ci_form_validation->_error_array displays my errors?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I've built a simple form validation, I intend to use it for ajax calls but right now I can't seem to get my error messages? I know that the form validator is running and weirder still I can see my error that I want in `ci_form_validation->_error_array` but this is a protected property :( (this is when I printed the class)

The form validator is working correctly! I've used this method thousands of times before yet I can't seem to get my error messages this time and I have no idea why? I'll keep the code below simple, for testing I've pretty much removed everything.

Ajax controller (parts removed)

```
<?if(!defined('BASEPATH'))die();
class Ajax extends MY_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        //if(!isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST))redirect('/','refresh');
        parent::__construct();
        //check this site with requested uri or request server url
        $this->con['validation']['add_user']=array(
            array('field'=>'firstname','label'=>'First name','rules'=>'max_length[30]|required|alpha'),
            array('field'=>'lastname','label'=>'Last name','rules'=>'max_length[30]|required|alpha'),
            array('field'=>'email','label'=>'Email address','rules'=>'required|is_unique[users.email]|max_length[150]|valid_email')                     
        );
        //$this->html->set_doc_type('html');//set application json
        //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    }
    public function add_user(){
        if($this->_fv('add_user')){
            $this->load->model('users');
            $result=$result=$this->users->insert($this->input->post('firstname'),$this->input->post('lastname'),$this->input->post('email'));
            //var_dump('hi there');
            echo $result;
        }else{
            var_dump($this->fv);
            var_dump($this->input->post());
            var_dump('returned false');
            var_dump(validation_errors());
            $result=array('firstname'=>form_error('firstname'),'lastname'=>form_error('lastname'),'email'=>form_error('email'));
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        $this->load->view('index/signup');
        //exit;
    }
}
```

My controller

```
<?if(!defined('BASEPATH'))die();
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public$con;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function _fv($form=null){
        if($form==null)return true;
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation'=>'fv'));
        $this->fv->set_rules($this->con['validation'][$form]);
        if($this->fv->run()===false){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, the weird thing is I can see the error message in the ci_form_validation object but it just doesn't display in `form_error()` or `validation_errors()`?

Have I missed an auto loaded library or helper? this is my loaders

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form'); 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('HTML'=>'html','database','session');
//HTML is my header and footer building library.
```

I don't get any PHP errors messages at all. Everything works as it should, I just don't get any error messages? :'(

The error message I want is is_uniqiue.

```
["_error_array":protected]=> array(1) { ["email"]=> string(52) "The Email address field must contain a unique value." }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. My guess is that there's something wrong with my way of working? But I have no idea what. I kind of cheated with my solution but if you have any ideas let me know! :)

```
<?if(!defined('BASEPATH'))die();
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function get_errors(){
        return$this->_error_array;
    }
}
```